# How to run Wordpress Query by ACF field using Select on front-end

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Basically what I'm trying to do is create filters on front end, so that users can filter all posts by specific ACF field.

There's a cattery website and the owner will need to add new litters, when new generations of kittens arrive. I've created option page for this new field group and created a repeater field with text, so that I can add new rows with names of the litters, I want to filter by later.

I've included basic loop for repeater field:

```
<select name="litter" id="litter">
  <?php
  
  if( have_rows('cat-litters', 'option') ):
    
    while ( have_rows('cat-litters', 'option') ) : the_row(); ?>

      <option value="<?php the_sub_field('new-litter', 'option'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('new-litter', 'option'); ?></option>

    <?php endwhile;
  else :
      
  endif;
  ?>
</select>
```

And it is working for now: [image]

I will be adding a field to cats' posts named cat-litter, so that I can find specific posts with a litter "02" for example.

But now I'm stuck with using this select from front-end to run a query to display fitting posts.
I'm working in index.php of twentytwentyone child-theme btw.

It doesn't matter if it will need to reload page or not (however if the ajax way won't be complicated I would very much appreciate that) but I have to point out that it needs to work with pagination and I already have it set up with pre_get_posts to display 9 posts per page (3x3 grid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken and modified from the `Dynamic $_GET parameters` section of this page per the ACF documentation: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // do not modify queries in the admin
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return $query;
    }

    // only modify queries for 'cat' post type
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'cat' ) {
        
        // allow the url to alter the query
        if( isset($_GET['cat-litter']) ) {
            $query->set('meta_key', 'cat-litter');
            $query->set('meta_value', $_GET['cat-litter']);
        } 
    }
    
    // return
    return $query;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

Then on the front end for reloading the page with the 'cat-litter' from the dropdown could be done with jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('select#litter').on('change', function() {
      window.location.href = "www.website.com/cats?cat-litter=" + $(this).val();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't have a custom post type for that so I struggled a bit with implementing that, maybe the hour has already been too late, but thanks for reminding me about url parameters. Did some tweaks around them and got it working. The only thing thats not working with it is pagination, but I'm sure I'll figure it out too. Thanks!